# Push Notification received but not displayed (Flutter / Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Notification in json is well received by the phone receiver and there is a print with json content in 'onMessage'. However no notifications is shown on the screen. Here is the json code sent :

```
    var client = http.Client();

    var jsonData = json.encode({
                "to": "/topics/$userId",
                "notification": {
                  "body": "$notificationText",
                  "title": "Title",
                },
                "data": {
                  "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
                  "sound": "default",
                  "status": "done",
                  "screen": "ListPostsScreen",
                },
                "content_available": true,
                "priority": "high",
              });

              var headers = {
                'Authorization': "key=$key",
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              };

    var response = await client.post(url, headers: headers, body: jsonData);

    print(response.body);
```

firebaseMessaging in home screen :

```
final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
    firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS ? null : myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
```

This is the intent-filter in main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

My pubspec.yaml packages :

```
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6
```

Did I miss something ?
Thank you.

Comment: What are you using to send the notifications? And to receive them? Are you using any package?

Comment: I use firebase cloud messaging :
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9, 
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2, 
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5; 
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6,

Comment: What is the message you see when the app crashes?

Comment: It says that the app stopped working. Do you think I can see error message in the console, on the phone which receives the notification ? When I did the test, only mobile which send notifications was in USB so I did not see error message in other side

Comment: Try to connect the phone that crashes and see what is the error when it crashes. Maybe it has nothing to do with the notification.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of a silly addition but I was having the same problem and realized my **Do-Not-Disturb** was turned on. I didn't think anything of it however because I had turned it off.

However, I guess because it was on a schedule it was still blocking notifications. I now have them working properly at the time of typing this - on **iOS 13.5** displaying in the background.

### Resources

https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-push-notifications-fcm-guide/

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

https://github.com/fireship-io/192-flutter-fcm-push-notifications/blob/master/lib/main.dart